I am having trouble using an NPN transistor as a switch
I'm attempting to use an NPN transistor as a switch in a 3.3V electrical circuit, and have been encountering some difficulties getting it to work properly.

I have a basic understanding of electronics and transistors. As far as I understand it, an NPN transistor can let current pass from the collector to the emitter if a voltage is applied to the gate.
As a simple example that illustrates my issue, here is a simple NOT-gate circuit, created in the Falstad Circuit Simulator:

The logic input marked with the letter H in the image above is inverted in the wire labeled with Output. The circuit above is able to make the Output node see either 3.3V (when the transistor is inactive), or see ~0V ground ( when the transistor is active).
In the Falstad Simulator, the NPN transistor appears to switch between the active & inactive "states" at a certain gate voltage threshold, which appears to lie between 0.5V and 0.7V:

Meaning that I can essentially switch between the "On" and "Off" states of the transistor within that ~0.2V window:

This is roughly how I have always assumed transistors to work, and in this simulator and other simillar circuit simulators, it works that way.

Attempting to replicate the same circuit behavior with a physical transistor is proving a bit difficult.
I've assembled the same circuit on a breadboard, using the BC337 NPN transistor from a transistor kit, with the logic power provided by an ESP32 microcontroller (with 3.3V digital pins):

Where I just read the Output wire on a multimeter.
The following simple Arduino program uploaded from an Arduino IDE instance to the ESP32, allows me to just change the analog output of the pin that's connected to the gate of the transistor:
byte gateVoltage = 0;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
    gateVoltage = Serial.readString().toInt();
  Serial.println("Gate voltage: " + String(gateVoltage));
  analogWrite(4, gateVoltage);
  delay(500);
}

Running the setup above with a voltage of 3.3V applied to the transistor gate yields ~0V on the Output wire, and voltage of 0V applied to the transistor gate yields ~3.3V, both expected results.
In the simulators, we had a very brief switching window between the two "states" of the transistor, but here it does not appear to be like that. There is a much more continuous range of voltages seen on the Output wire between the 3.3V and 0V applied to the gate. In the simulators, the transistor would switch between the two "states" between 0.5V and 0.7V, the physical transistor appears to provide voltage to the Output wire inversely-proportional to the amount of voltage applied to its gate:

For example, in the simulator a voltage of 1.5V applied to the gate yielded 0V on the Output wire, yet the physical transistor with a 1.5V gate voltage yields an Output voltage of ~1.8V.
I have also tried the same setup with several other simillar NPN transistors:

C1815
S8050
2N2222
2N2907
2N3904

I also tried it with different breadboards, wires & microcontrollers, all with virtually the same results.

Is it possible to use a physical NPN transistor as an (almost) instantaneous switch in the same manner that many of the circuit simulators implement them? Is there perhaps a specific type of NPN transistor that is better suited to this application, other than the ones I've already tried?

An NPN transistor does not have a gate; it has a base for the input connection. Also what does throughput mean?

Is the DAC in the ESP32 being used to generate the output voltage connected by a 1K resistor to the base of the NPN transistor? If so, what is the output impedance of the DAC? On a quick search couldn't seem to find the DAC output impedance documented.

the 'analog output' is actually PWM. If you're reading the output voltage of your gate with a meter, that will average the output voltage, giving you the continuous variation you observe.

Beautifully written story , but  details in test results are lacking.All transistors have nonlinear current gain that is voltage  dependent and cannot alone be abrupt switches.  Did you verify your test connections and values are accurate? One might think you had CE connections reversed  with almost unity current gain.  TTL inverters also have a linear switching range  near two diode drops (by design) but that range is not zero and use more than 1 transistor to defined levels. So logic must use margins to avoid static levels between "0&1" e.g. TTL must be <=0.8 or >=2.0V

Why does the current appear to move the wrong direction in that simulation video?

@marcelm Falstad's simulator lets you display the current either in the conventional direction or backwards from the conventional direction, so the asker here must have it set to show backwards.


Is it possible to use a physical NPN transistor as an (almost) instantaneous switch in the same manner that many of the circuit simulators implement them?

For once, the simulators are doing a good job. "Instantaneous" switching is exactly what you're observing! The multimeter obscures the fact that the output of the transistor is not a constant voltage, but a square wave with varying duty cycle.
The transistor works very nicely. There is no "analog" output on an ESP. All you get is a variable ratio between ON time and OFF time. The transistor follows that ratio in its switching, and your multimeter does a fine job averaging the voltage. The voltage measured by the multimeter is
$$D.\!C. \times V_{CC}=D.\!C.\times3.3{\rm\ V}$$. D.C. is the duty cycle and ranges from 0.0 (0%) to 1.0 (100%).
Here is what is happening:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The ESP32 output voltage is the orange trace, the OUT voltage is the blue trace. The transistor acts as an inverter.

The get the analog behavior you're looking for, you need to convert the PWM waveform into a relatively constant voltage that then feeds the base resistor. This is done by a so-called reconstruction filter.
Since the goal here is to measure what's going on with Q1, you can for the moment ignore what exactly happens with Q2 and Q3 - suffice to say that they buffer the voltage on C1 and C2 and and convert PWM into an analog voltage.

simulate this circuit
It takes about 0.1s for the analog output voltage to settle to its desired value after changing the PWM duty cycle. The plot below shows the voltage on the input to Rb after step from 0% to 50% duty cycle:

The reason for using Q2 and Q3, and not filtering directly at the base, is so that we can be sure that the behavior of Q1 that we observe is not some artifact of how the analog voltage is obtained.

Thanks for your clear answer. It makes total sense to me now, not sure how I didn't think of the PWM cycles switching the transistor super fast... I assumed however that signal generated by PWM would be the same as a purely analog signal, such as one from a DC power supply, since they could both give continous voltage signals. Clearly I was wrong, building that reconstruction filter circuit you showed straight-up worked for my application! With that circuit before the input to the NOT-gate, the transistors now all work as in the simulators. Thank you!

But the ESP32 setup does not match the simulated scenario.
The ESP32 does not have an analog output. It has a PWM output which is 0V or 3.3V but with a percentage for the duty cycle at some high frequency.
Basicaly your setup is trying to turn the transistor on and off thousands or tens of thousads of times per second.
Also bipolar transistors have a base instead of a gate, and the collector current is proportional to the base current.
An ideal diode model may have a defined threshold when it conducts and does not, but in reality the voltage knee has a wide range.
So assuming the transistor is ideal, and you drive it 50% on and 50% off, your measurements are indicating exactly that when averaged.

Thanks for this clear & concise answer. It makes total sense to me now, the PWM cycles were just causing the transistor to switch between the two "states" too fast.

Not so much an answer, but an addition for you to think about.
A Transistor is for the most part a current amplifier Ie=Ic+Ib (If I remember right). While it has a .7v turn on threshold (Vbe).  Hfe is a kind of multiplier, IbXhfe results in Ie emitter current. A FET may be more of what you may want to use, as it's more of a "switch" and does not depend on Ib or base current to keep it "on".
Also, most digital chips can "sink" more current than they can "source". This means that if you are expecting enough current from the IC to drive the transistor, the IC may not be able to supply this current.
Then you also have to think about "float" not sure if anyone thinks about that - but when the IC is in a non-sink state, is it actually doing what you want to the transistor. The Digital IC is expecting another Digital IC to be connected to it, not a transistor.
You may want to attach a 10K - 50K resistor from the base to the 3.3v rail to keep the transistor "on" when the IC chip goes "hi" And a small capacitor maybe .2uf or so Base to Ground to keep the bounce to a minimum.
Good luck with your project.
